# set enviroment variable in python to run program

Tags: python, visual-studio

I am running visual studio, and to run the program I usually just hit `ctrl+F5`.
Now I am trying to write a python script to run this program with several different configurations.

So far I have something like

```
cmd = "mycmd.exe arg1 arg2"
os.system(cmd)
```

but this fails with a message `ERROR: environment variable TZ not set correctly`.
I checked in visual studio and in the property windows, under config in the debuggin tab there is a setting for the `TZ` variable,

```
Enviroment   TZ=XXX
```

How can I tell python to use the same setting when running the program?
Is `os.system` the best solution to run this or are there better alternatives?

Thanks!

Comment: You definitely don't want the same setting, as the XXX string is what's faulty.  Do you know where visual-studio gets this setting from?

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain my self well enough. The setting is correct in visual studio (of course it is not XXX it is GMT), but I didn't know how to set the enviroment variable in python when running the program and so it was giving an error. The answer bellow from Maulwurfn solves this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import os
os.environ['FOO'] = 'bar'
```

Python will call the underlaying os.putenv() method under the hood automatically

http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.putenv

Comment: That would work for this instance, but I think the OP's visual studio environment may need fixing.  The next project that tries something similar will also run into this.

Comment: I don't think that the enviroment in visual studio needs fixing. The variable `TZ` is explicitly set there so the program runs correctly from visual studio. I just didn't know how to make it work in python.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative that I found after @Maulwurfn answer
is the following

```
import subprocess
import os

my env = os.environ
my_env['TZ'] = 'XXX'
p = suprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, env=my_env)

while p.poll() is None:
  time.sleep(2)
```

If I don't add the while loop all the configurations start running at about the same time.

Comment: Note that you need to *copy* the `environ` dict; you are still manipulating `os.environ` albeit through a reference. `my_env = os.environ.copy()` would be closer to your intent.